# Angular Directive: Adding ng-class directive at compile time on existing template element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Long story short, the idea is to simplify templating by not having to manually add `ng-class={'has-error': 'formName.inputName.$invalid'}` on every single `form-group`**

So I want to create a directive that will generate a string that will be added to a template element. That string is an `ng-class` attribute with an expression

I thought that creating a quick directive that adds the ng-class attribute during the compile phase would be enough, but it doesn't seem to cut it.

### Directive Definition Object

```
{
    restrict: 'C',
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
        var $elem = angular.element(tElement),
            formName = $elem.parents('[ng-form]').length ? $elem.parents('[ng-form]').attr('ng-form') : $elem.parents('form').attr('name'),
            controlName = $elem.find('.form-control').attr('name');

        $elem.attr('ng-class', '{"has-error": ' + formName + '.' + controlName + '.$invalid}');

        console.log('added ng-class attr', $elem.attr('ng-class'));
    }
}
```

### [Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/n1jf5FPtAzueLnELaQcO?p=preview)

See the console

> The 1st `form-group` has its `ng-class` attribute added dynamically.
>   The expression associated with it is correct
>   But the `ng-class` directive is never executed
>
> The 2nd `form-group` has its `ng-class` attribute added manually in the template and works as expected, obvisouly

--

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed to make it work without adding extra watchers (granted, ng-class uses a watcher, but after testing the proposed solution I saw an increase in watchers amount)

I had to $compile the new DOM element in postLink, but to avoid recursion I need to remove the directive itself. This prevents me to reuse a class-name such as "form-group"

Here's the working Directive

```
function bsFormClass($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',

    compile: function (tElement) {

        var $elem = angular.element(tElement),
            controlName = $elem.find('.form-control').attr('name');

        if(!controlName) { return; }

        var formName = $elem.parents('[ng-form]').length ? $elem.parents('[ng-form]').attr('ng-form') : $elem.parents('form').attr('name');

        $elem.attr('ng-class', '{"has-error": ' + formName + '.' + controlName + '.$invalid}');
        $elem.removeAttr('bs-form-class');

        return {
            post: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                $compile(elem)(scope);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for you help all

Comment: This approach doesn't work if there is an ng-if in the parent element.

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** add directives to the current element!

In your case the solution is easy though; just watch the appropriate expressions and add the class as necessary:

```
function formGroupClass () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var formName = elem.parents('[ng-form]').length ? elem.parents('[ng-form]').attr('ng-form') : elem.parents('form').attr('name'),
                controlName = elem.find('.form-control').attr('name');

            scope.$watch(formName + '.' + controlName + '.$invalid', function(newval) {
              elem.toggleClass('has-error', !!newval);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

The `ng-class` would add a watch anyway... See forked plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/oKa6CKFoF1T5WoDzIPkI?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, I kind of wanted to avoir sprinkling $watchers everywhere like this :/
Good point on ng-class adding a watcher
Thanks though

Comment: I'm kind of confused what you are trying to accomplish @OlivierClément. You want to add `ng-class` dynamically based on some directive value? If it's worth anything, here is a hacky way you might be able to do this: [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h7oodL52/). Of course this is just simplified, but maybe helpful?

Comment: @scniro I added some precision regarding my intentions (in bold, top of the question). Your fiddle could work, but I want to keep it as light as possible as doing those manipulation in the link function could become expensive very quickly, and the form that's going to be used will eventually have north of 50-60 fields per pages or so

Comment: This solution has the additional benefit of not conflicting with existing an `ng-class` directive on the element. Otherwise, you'd have to figure out how to reconcile them.